# How to use lxc_container module in Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, lxc, devops

I am trying to run this playbook

```
---
- hosts: control
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Stop All Linux Containers
      lxc_container: name={{ item }} state=started
      with_items:
        - app01
        - app02
        - lb01
        - db01
```

the target host is localhost but it is failing and showing following error

```
failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=app01) => {"failed": true, "item": "app01",    "parsed": false}
BECOME-SUCCESS-rppgggxcewgndkgtnpptrgeglbfykput
failed=True msg='The lxc module is not importable. Check the requirements.'
The lxc module is not importable. Check the requirements
```

After this I tried

```
pip install lxc-python2
```

(saw it from another stackoverflow post) But it is showing an error too

```
lxc.c:27:30: fatal error: lxc/lxccontainer.h: No such file or directory

 #include <lxc/lxccontainer.h>

                              ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_dhruv/lxc-python2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ZKdf9M-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_dhruv/lxc-python2
Storing debug log for failure in /home/dhruv/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if you have not installed the `lxc-dev` package. At the moment it happens that the debian repo doesn't contain it and you have to download from a third party like [ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc)

Comment: had same error in this question and lxc-dev did the trick! thanks

Answer (score 0):

That dev package (lxc-dev), or pip is not needed to be present in target hosts for normal operation of lxc_container -Ansible module. Only python2 is required to be present in target hosts and those packages listed in LXC-container module documentation in management host (the one in which u run Ansible).